# FCM notification in terminated state runs main twice and leads to ANR

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented push notification using firebase_messaging and flutter_local_notifications. What I did is setting a background `handler(FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler))` for notification received in background and terminate state and `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage(_handler)` for the foreground one.What the handlers does is using flutterNotificationPlugin to show the notification banner and after it is tapped the user navigate to a specific route.

Foreground and Background notifications work very well, but the terminated state ones get an application not responding after 10 seconds that the navigation is completed. I checked the logs and I found out that the main is executed twice. The first one when the notification is received and the second one when it’s tapped and consequently the app opened. Probably is the first instance which gets an ANR after a while.

What I expected is that in the terminate state only the method with u/pragma('vm:entry-point'), which is `firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler`, is executed, not the whole main. I tried to kill the first thread but It didn’t fix the ANR.

Do you have any advice?

Thanks